# Fonts starts looks like vector graphic

Tags: css, fonts, gulp-sass

Yesterday everything was okey, today morning all fonts on my website start looks like that:
[image]
Same situation in chrome/opera/firefox. Nobody changed nothing. Maybe some changes in browsers? Whats a possible problem?

Comment: What was the original font?

Comment: @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi Montserrat - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

Comment: Maybe send a sandbox to get a debug for this issue.

Comment: Please show how you are selecting that font.